# What does the following lines mean from kernel makefiles?

Tags: linux, makefile, kernel, kbuild

The following code are extracted from kernel source

```
$(real-objs-m) : modkern_cflags := $(CFLAGS_MODULE)
$(real-objs-m) : quiet_modtag := [M]
$(multi-objs-m) : modname = $(modname-multi)
```

Comment: Looks like ["Target-specific Variable Values"](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific).

Comment: Really thanks for your help!!!! You have no idea how long I have been searching for this!!!!